# C# equivalent of C++ map<string,double>

Tags: c#, arrays, hashmap

I want to keep some totals for different accounts. In C++ I'd use STL like this:

```
map<string,double> accounts;

// Add some amounts to some accounts.
accounts["Fred"] += 4.56;
accounts["George"] += 1.00;
accounts["Fred"] += 1.00;

cout << "Fred owes me $" << accounts['Fred'] << endl;
```

Now, how would I do the same thing in C# ?

Comment: **C# Dictionary** is equivalent to **C++ unordered_map**.  Furthermore, **C# SortedDictionary** is equivalent to **C++ map**.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Roughly:-

```
var accounts = new Dictionary<string, double>();

// Initialise to zero...

accounts["Fred"] = 0;
accounts["George"] = 0;
accounts["Fred"] = 0;

// Add cash.
accounts["Fred"] += 4.56;
accounts["George"] += 1.00;
accounts["Fred"] += 1.00;

Console.WriteLine("Fred owes me ${0}", accounts["Fred"]);
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, the only drawback is I do not know what the names of the accounts will be ahead of time.

Comment: You don't need to know them ahead of time. The examples use constant strings for brevity, but you can use string objects.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify that comment by saying "I do not know the names, or how many names I will have". In this answer, if I added accounts["Ron"] += 2.50;, it would throw an exception. In reality, I'll be throwing an XML file at it with lots of names and numbers.

Comment: Actually no, if you use the index and attempt to set a non-existent key, it will actually create the object for you with the specified key. An exception will only be thrown on the get operation.

Look here on remarks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx

Comment: Erebus is correct: You can arbitrarily add things to a Dictionary without knowing at compile time what or how many elements will be in the dictionary.

Comment: Why people so much like `var`?

Comment: @Alex: because var is much shorter than IParallelEnumerable<Record<string,XmlSerializer>> :)

Comment: Dictionaries in c# are not equivalent to stl::map's just so you know - c# dictionaries are hash tables whereas stl::map's are red-black trees, the underlying algorithms are totally different.

Comment: Note, that the `accounts["Fred"] = 0;`in this example is equivalent to `accounts.Add("Fred", 0);` (See https://dotnetfiddle.net/q3UteL for both variants)
Also:
*When you use `Dictionary.Add( Key, Value )` to add a new `KeyValuePair` an **`ArgumentException`** will be thrown if the `Key` already exists in the dictionary.  
*Using the indexer (`Dictionary[ Key ]`) you get an implicit **add-or-update** behavior since the `Key` will automatically be added if it is not contained in the Dictionary already otherwise the corresponding value will simply be updated. *Consider using decimal for currency

Answer (score 20):

```
Dictionary<string, double> accounts;
```

Answer (score 17):

Although System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary matches the tag "hashmap" and will work well in your example, it is not an exact equivalent of C++'s std::map - std::map is an ordered collection.

If ordering is important you should use [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You want the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is the most common, but you can use other types of collections, e.g. 
System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedKeyedCollection, System.Collections.Hashtable, or any KeyValuePair collection

Comment: Is it true that C# Dictionary is equivalent to C++ unordered_map ? If yes, then the question is: What is the C# equivalence of C++ map ?

Answer (score 2):

This code is all you need:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
        String xml = @"
            <transactions>
                <transaction name=""Fred"" amount=""5,20"" />
                <transaction name=""John"" amount=""10,00"" />
                <transaction name=""Fred"" amount=""3,00"" />
            </transactions>";

        XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var query = from x in xmlDocument.Descendants("transaction")
                    group x by x.Attribute("name").Value into g
                    select new { Name = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(t => Decimal.Parse(t.Attribute("amount").Value)) };

        foreach (var item in query) {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Amount: {1:C};", item.Name, item.Amount);
        }
    }
```

And the content is:

Name: Fred; Amount: R$ 8,20;

Name: John; Amount: R$ 10,00;

That is the way of doing this in C# - in a declarative way!

I hope this helps,

Ricardo Lacerda Castelo Branco

Comment: Well, I've already done it with Dictionary now but the XML is real simple, just a list of tags like this: <transaction name="Fred" amount="5.20" />

Answer (score 1):

While we are talking about STL, maps and dictionary, I'd recommend taking a look at the [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) library.  It offers several types of dictionaries and maps that I've frequently found useful (along with many other interesting and useful data structures).

If you are a C++ programmer moving to C# as I did, you'll find this library a great resource (and a data structure for this  dictionary).

-Paul

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent of C++ `std::map<>` (a tree internally) is C# `OrderedDictionary<>` (a tree internally), while C# `OrderedDictionary<>` is missing some very important methods from C++ `std::map<>`, namely: `std::map::find`, `std::map::lower_bound`, `std::map::upper_bound`, `std::map::equal_range`, and `std::map` `iterators`, which are basically the backbone for the previous 4 methods.

Why those 4 methods are important? Because it gives us the ability to locate the "whereabouts" of a given key, in addition to only being able to check if a key exists, or the SortedDictionary is guaranteed to be ordered.

What is "whereabouts" of a key in a `std::map`? The key doesn't necessarily have to exist in the collection, we want to know the location the key might be at, usually between two iterators pointing to two adjacent existing keys respectively in the collection, so we can operate on the **range** the key falls into in a `O(logN)` complexity. Without such 4 methods (with iterators), one has to do an `O(N)` iteration through the collection every time a range is queried against a key.